# Pure Javascript super simple slideshow image number counter?

Tags: javascript, html, image, web, slideshow

**The issue is I would like to implement a slide counter underneath a image slideshow stating the current slide number against the slide total, e.g '1 of 3' etc.**

Being a complete javascript novice I am struggling to find something that works with the existing code I have implemented. — Would appreciate the help to find a solution and implement the slide counter

*I have used a some pure javascript pulled it from w3 schools example for a image slideshow and it works great, example can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self). (Would very much like to keep the next / prev functions the same, i.e cursor click left/right of image)*

https://jsfiddle.net/TEK22/1s205La6/

```css
.project {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5% 20% 5% 20%;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.imgslide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.prev {
  cursor: zoom-out;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.next {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
 <div class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"></div>
 <div class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1)"></div>
 <div class="imgslide noselect">
     <img class="slides" src="https://i.imgur.com/Xhu0Qz8.png">
     <img class="slides" src="https://i.imgur.com/arLyQDw.jpg">
     <img class="slides" src="https://i.imgur.com/tbpcx4i.png">
 </div>
</div>

<script>

 var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is just showing `slideIndex` of `x.length` in pagination area like this?

1. Add `<div class="pagination"><div>` to html code.
2. Add `document.getElementsByClassName("pagination")[0].innerText = slideIndex + ' of ' + x.length;` to script.

```css
.project {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5% 20% 5% 20%;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.imgslide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.prev {
  cursor: zoom-out;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.next {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
 <div class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"></div>
 <div class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1)"></div>
 <div class="imgslide noselect">
     <img class="slides" src="https://i.imgur.com/Xhu0Qz8.png">
     <img class="slides" src="https://i.imgur.com/arLyQDw.jpg">
     <img class="slides" src="https://i.imgur.com/tbpcx4i.png">
 </div>
  <div class="pagination"><div>
</div>

<script>

 var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  document.getElementsByClassName("pagination")[0].innerText = slideIndex + ' of ' + x.length;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is great, however the code you have added seems to effect the rest of the code above and beneath it. 

E.g if I had a section of <p> text underneath <div class="project"> as you have coded it it won't display....

Got a js.fiddle of what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/TEK22/1s205La6/6/

Comment: Nevermind!! turns out, I just needed to close the pagination div!!